# create a static folder independent with Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, customization

I have a website: www.a.com
I want to add a folder of code samples like this: www.a.com/code//index.html
So that at the end of each post I can refer the user to an example. How can I create a static folder independent with Wordpress that can be accessed from the outside?

Comment: Use the File Manager from cPanel or use a FTP account, and easily create your folder wherever you want and then direct the user with its real path `http://example.com/code/somepath/index.html`. It should work. What's the mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the File Manager from cPanel or use a FTP account, and easily create your folder wherever you want and then direct the user with its real path something like:

```
http://example.com/code/somepath/index.html
```

It should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for code samples, you can't beat putting them in a Git repository, then just putting a link into your posts. For public Gits, you could use Github or Bitbucket. Like this:

```
 https://bitbucket.org/Hitman007/crg_login/src
```